# I want to add media player controls in the Alert Dialog Box

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-alertdialog

I am working on a project which requires the background text to speech to play, pause or stop on the onClick option of the Dialog Box. Currently it plays the audio normally after the listview onclick but I can't figure out how to pause or stop the ongoing audio. Here is the MainActivity code:

```
    listViewSMS.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                View v, int position, long arg3) {
            // when user clicks on ListView Item , onItemClick is called
            // with position and View of the item which is clicked
            // we can use the position parameter to get index of clicked item


            TextView textViewSMSSender = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewSMSSender);
            TextView textViewSMSBody = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessageBody);

            smsSender = textViewSMSSender.getText().toString();//to get the sender in string
            smsBody = textViewSMSBody.getText().toString();// content of the sms into string


            // Show The Dialog with Selected SMS  when particular sms selected
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            dialog.setTitle("SMS From : " + smsSender);
            dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.iltts);
            dialog.setMessage(smsBody);

            //Dialog box button click event to read the selected sms from the shown list
            dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Play",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            Log.d("send", smsSender);
                            Log.d("body", smsBody + " " + spinnerValue);

                            //***************############################################28112013
                            //online part added

                            MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
                            myTask.execute(smsBody);

                            //#############################################################

                            return;
                        }
                    });

            dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Pause", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            //Log.d("send", smsSender);
                            //Log.d("body", smsBody + " " + spinnerValue);

                            //***************############################################28112013
                            //online part added
                            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                            mediaPlayer.pause();}
                            //#############################################################

                            return;
                        }
                    }
            );
            dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL,"Stop",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                            mediaPlayer.stop();
                            mediaPlayer.release();
                        }
                    }
            );



            dialog.show();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

//ToGo to text to speech engine selection
public void goPreferences(View v)
{
    //f=2;

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

}
//Online part with Asynctask ########################################################################################################

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"","Please Wait",false); 

    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //Some calculations...

        String nt=params[0];        

        lang=spinnerValue.toLowerCase();

        //for bengali hts 
        if(lang.equals("bengali")){
            lang="hts"+lang;
            Log.d("bengali language test ********************* ", lang);

        }
        //for gujarati hts
        else if(lang.equals("gujarati")){
            lang="hts"+lang+"_male";
            Log.d("gujarati language test ********************* ", lang);

        }

        //for kannada hts
        else if(lang.equals("kannada")){
            lang="hts"+lang+"_female";
            Log.d("kannada language test ********************* ", lang);

        }

        /* <item>English_Hindi</item>                      
            <item>English_Tamil</item>        
            <item>English_Telugu</item> */

        else if(lang.equals("english_hindi")){
            lang="htsenglish";
            Log.d("English (hindi) language test ********************* ", lang);

        }
        //htstelugueng
        else if(lang.equals("english_telugu")){
            lang="htstelugueng";
            Log.d("English (Telugu) language test ********************* ", lang);

        }
        else if(lang.equals("english_tamil")){
            lang="htstamileng";
            Log.d("English (Tamil) language test ********************* ", lang);
        }
        else{
            Log.d(" language test ********************* ", lang);
        }
        //rate
        speed=rateselected.toLowerCase();
        vc="";
        Log.d("language selected now ", lang);
        //PART1.1
        //link="http://tts.cdacmumbai.in/festival_cs_apps.php";   //amr type v.1.0
        //link="http://202.141.151.29/festival_cs_apps.php"; 
        //link="http://iltts.in/festival_cs_apps.php";//2014 Sep 11 v.1.1
        link="http://tdil-dc.in/tts/festival_cs_apps.php";//2015 march 14 july 02 v1.4
        Log.d("Value of lang" , spinnerValue);
        //generating random number
        rannum=Math.random();
        Log.d("Randum number generated ", Double.toString(rannum));
        count=Double.toString(rannum);
        Log.d("body from params0", nt);
        Log.d("body of smsBody", smsBody);
        Log.d("desired url", link);
        Log.d("counter", count);

        try{

            // Creating HTTP client
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Creating HTTP Post
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(link);

            //Name value pair created what you want to send to server
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Languages",lang));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("voice",vc));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ex","execute"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("op",smsBody));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("count",count));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("speed",speed));
            //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, "UTF-8")); // UTF 8 added to send indic string to server
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            final int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.d("Response Status Code",String.valueOf(statusCode));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //Part1.2

        //link2="http://tts.cdacmumbai.in/wav_output/"; 

        //link2="http://202.141.151.29/wav_output/"; 

        //link2="http://iltts.in/wav_output/";//2014 Sep 11 v1.1
        link2="http://tdil-dc.in/tts/wav_output/";//2015 March 14  July 02 v 1.4
        //file type
        file2download=link2+"fest_out"+count+".amr";
        Log.d("Now Listen this ",file2download);
        return file2download;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //Log.d("Listen file in postexecute   check and enjoy*********************", result);

        pd.dismiss();
        String url = result;// your URL here
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);             

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.release();
            }
        });

    }//post execute ends

}//MyTask  class ends
```

}//MainActivity ends

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/protocol10/ASplayer

Comment: I think you need 2 different objects of media palyer because on click of listview 1st one is paused on after playing second media 1st one will get resume